# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'types'

Tags: python, dataframe

Does anyone have any ideas  on why I am getting the following error when I try to print out columns data types of a df using the:

```
 print(df.types)
```

command

```
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'types'
```

There are no duplicate values in the column names of the df.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`df.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) instead?

Comment: yes, is df.dtypes like Mihai says!

Comment: Yeap, that was it - thanks for the prompt replies and the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a small typo in your example. In order to print columns data types of a dataframe you have to write: `print(df.dtypes)`

Here is the corresponding documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html